# C# Mongo BsonSerializer.Deserialize not coverting to a BsonDocumentBackedClass as expected

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using C#, 2.0 .net MongoDb drivers,

I take a class that converters a BsonDocumentBackedClass to a bsondocument and save it into mongo.  I do the conversion so I can inject other properties that are only relevant at the repository layer and do not want it passed back to the client applications.

I also have the conversion setup to ignore properties that are null or default.

When I get the BsonDocument and attempt to run it through the following

```
public static T MapTo<T>(BsonDocument item)
{
    return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(item);
}
```

Properties that currently do not exist on the bson document throw the following exception

```
IsDeleted' threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
```

On the BsonDocumentBackedClass I have tried to set the following

```
[DataMember, BsonElement, BsonDefaultValue(false)]
public bool IsDeleted {
    get { return BackingDocument["IsDeleted"].AsBoolean; }
    set { BackingDocument["IsDeleted"] = value; }
}
```

For the BsondocumentBackClass I have the following setup for the serializer

```
/// <summary>
/// Poco to Bson map
/// </summary>
public class BsonParentClassSerializer : BsonDocumentBackedClassSerializer<BsonParent>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Init
    /// </summary>
    public BsonParentClassSerializer()
    {
        this.RegisterMember("DateCreated", "DateCreated", new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc));
        this.RegisterMember("DateModified", "DateModified", new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc));
        this.RegisterMember("UserModified", "UserModified", new StringSerializer());
        this.RegisterMember("IsDeleted", "IsDeleted", new BooleanSerializer());
    }

    protected override BsonParent CreateInstance(BsonDocument backingDocument)
    {
        return new BsonParent(backingDocument, this);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the serializer I need to setup a default for the fields that might not exist or if there is something else I need to do.  Or if I just need to remove the IgnoreIfDefaultConvention

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution

Before I was doing this

```
[DataMember, BsonElement, BsonDefaultValue(false)]
public bool IsDeleted {
    get { return BackingDocument["IsDeleted"].AsBoolean; }
    set { BackingDocument["IsDeleted"] = value; }
}
```

looks like this is acceptable

```
[DataMember, BsonElement]
public bool IsDeleted {
    get { return BackingDocument["IsDeleted", false]; }
    set { BackingDocument["IsDeleted"] = value; }
}
```

And it appears in the 2.0 .net driver this is the direction they are heading

```
[DataMember, BsonElement]
public bool IsDeleted {
    get { return GetValue("IsDeleted", false); }
    set { SetValue("IsDeleted", value); }
}
```